# Number of unique values for each value of another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R of this type:

| Protein | Peptides |
| --- | --- |
| Protein 1 | Peptide A |
| Protein 1 | Peptide A |
| Protein 1 | Peptide B |
| Protein 1 | Peptide C |
| Protein 2 | Peptide D |
| Protein 2 | Peptide E |

I would like to create a new column, which counts, for each protein, the number of unique peptides such as this:

| Protein | Peptide | Unique values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Protein 1 | Peptide A | 3 |
| Protein 1 | Peptide A | 3 |
| Protein 1 | Peptide B | 3 |
| Protein 1 | Peptide C | 3 |
| Protein 2 | Peptide D | 2 |
| Protein 2 | Peptide E | 2 |

How could I do that ?

I have tried

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$'Uniquevalues' = n_distinct(df$Peptide)
}
```

But it gives me the overall number of unique values in the whole 'peptide' column, not per protein.

Comment: You could use `dplyr` with a group by like this: `library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Protein) %>%
  mutate(Unique_values = n_distinct(Peptides))`

Answer (score 0):

In base R, use `ave()` to group on `Protein` with `length(unique(x))`:

```r
X = data.frame(Protein = c(rep("Protein 1", 4), rep("Protein 2", 2)),
               Peptide = paste("Peptide", LETTERS[c(1, 1:5)]))
X$UniqueValues = with(X, ave(Peptide, Protein, FUN = \(x) length(unique(x))))
X
#>     Protein   Peptide UniqueValues
#> 1 Protein 1 Peptide A            3
#> 2 Protein 1 Peptide A            3
#> 3 Protein 1 Peptide B            3
#> 4 Protein 1 Peptide C            3
#> 5 Protein 2 Peptide D            2
#> 6 Protein 2 Peptide E            2
```